# PostgreSQL - How to count when Distinct On

Tags: postgresql

How to get count of rows for each user_id

```
select distinct on (user_id) *
from some_table
```

As in such SQL:

```
select user_id, count(*)
from some_table
group by user_id
```

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: Your question isnt clear. What is wrong with the `group by` ?

Comment: The second query seems correct as Juan Carlos stated and provides the same results as my answer. More efficient too. But if you insist, there is an answer using DISTINCT ON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.user_id)
       a.*
FROM
(
    SELECT  user_id
            , count(*) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id)
    FROM some_table
) a
```

Comment: Just a group by can do the same

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to use `SELECT *` in order to get a "sample row", depending on how large your table is you may be able to use a correlated subquery to get the count of rows for that particular user id:

```
select distinct on (user_id) *
, (select count (1) 
   from some_table st2 
   where st2.user_id = some_table.user_id) as user_row_count
from some_table
```